# How to import one class and method instead of complete package from one file which is in A package to another Package In Python

Tags: python-3.x, package

**Hello everyone please help as I am new to python and I want to know that how I can Import one class from one package to another package**
eg:-
In Package A file name is func1.py
Now I want to import only one class lets GoodStudent in another package B in file func2
I have used this in the func2.py file from a package.func1 import GoodStudent but it's giving me o/p of both the class and function.

func1.py

```
def sum(x, y):
    print(x + y)`enter code here`
sum(20,40)

class GoodStudent:
    def __init__(self, location, name, age,xyz):
        self.location = location
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def GoodStudentInformation(self):
        print("Name:{}".format(self.name))
        print("Age:{}".format(self.age))
    def GoodEmployeeInformation(self):
        print("xyz:{}".format(self.xyz))
gs = GoodStudent('A', 'B', 7, 'QWERY')
gs.GoodStudentInformation()
gs.GoodEmployeeInformation()
class Employee:
```

Comment: ```from func1 import GoodStudent```

Comment: @itprorh66 Thanks!! But it's not working giving an error:-ImportError: cannot import name 'GoodStudent' from 'func1'

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?  Are Package A & Package B in the same directory or different directories?

Comment: Yes both are in the same directory

Comment: @ankitSharma `from .func1 import GoodStudent`